# swiffy input textfield workaround

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3

I'm a noob to this forum and a noob to javascript, but I know a fair share of as3.

So swiffy doesn't support input text-fields. I thought that a workaround would be to call a javascript function from the swiffy object (which I can do using callExternalInterface) which would load an HTML input text-field into an iFrame or a div on a higher z-index layer above my swiffy object, positioned exactly so it looks like it's all part of the swiffy object, but sadly my javascript knowledge is in its infancy.

I've been going at it, doing research, trying different things, for five or six hours now and everything I try doesnt work. I'm loading an external HTML file which defines the text-field, and so far I have gotten something to load, but it's all weird, and while it now shows up at the right position, it 'breaks' the layout of the site, and shows up in a little box that tells me I need a plug-in to do that.

This is what I have right now, and it's pathetic and doesn't even work at all.. (load_email is the javascript function Im calling from my flash file)

```
function load_email(){
document.getElementById("swiffycontainer").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" id="email.html" </object>'
placeDiv();
console.info("email0");
}



function placeDiv(x_pos, y_pos) {
  var d = document.getElementById('email.html');
  console.info("boo");
  d.style.position = "relative";
  d.style.left = 292+'px';
  d.style.top = 380+'px';
  d.style.zIndex =2000;
  console.info("boo2");
}
```

Pathetic, isn't it.

Please help?

ANSWERING MY OWN QUESTION:

Turns out this is all much simpler than I was making it out to be.

My friend in Pakistan helped me out over Skype, this is how to get input textfields into your swiffy via javascript, from there it should be possible to cobble together some kind of emailer:

You don't need to load any external html file, just delete that part. Then change the load_email function to something like this:

```
function load_email() {
    var inputFieldName = document.createElement("input");
        inputFieldName.type="text";
        inputFieldName.style.position = "absolute";
        inputFieldName.style.left = "292px";
        inputFieldName.style.top = "370px";
        inputFieldName.style.zIndex = 2000;
        swiffycontainer.appendChild(inputFieldName);
}
```

Bam. Good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Thanx to your anwser and using the code you posted I made another working demo for a flash file in actionscript 2, to interchange data between swiffy and javascript (in and out).

Here are the steps:

1) The key is to send the value to the swiffy object with this line in **javascript**:

> function sendValue() {
>               myValue=inputFieldName.value;
>               stage.setFlashVars('myMessageFromTextfield='+myValue);
>           }

2) Then, inside the fla file, in **actionscript2**, get the value:

> getValue = function() {
>       if(_level0.myMessageFromTextfield == "undefined" || _level0.myMessageFromTextfield == undefined) {
>           this.cat.animCat.myText.text = "";
>       } else {
>           this.cat.animCat.myText.text = _level0.myMessageFromTextfield;
>           returnButton._visible = true;
>       }
>   }

3) We need to constantly monitor when te data apears so use a setInterval:

> myInterval = setInterval(this, "getValue", 100);

4) Now, to send the value back to html file, we use getURL with the data attached:

> returnButton.onRelease = function() {
>       getURL("Javascript:showMessage('"+_level0.myMessageFromTextfield+" says the cat');");
>   }

5) And finally, again in **javascript** inside the html we execute the function with the parameter:

> function showMessage(message) {
>               alert(message);
>           }

It works perfectly in IE, Firefox, Chrome, safari (ios).

So now we can send text in ipad or iphone.

I attached the source files in the next link:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E64343A7ADE7D670!1401&authkey=!AO86aUEdyZRqQN4&ithint=file%2czip